# How to build a class that exposes data while calling a instance of it?

Tags: python

Really don't know how to explain this without an example.
My goal is to create python class that shows data while calling the object itself.

A user defined class should works like this:

```
>>> class MyObject(object):
>>>   def __init__(self):
>>>     self.a = 12
>>>
>>> i = MyObject()
>>> i
<__main__.MyObject object at 0x7f667e7a78d0>
```

While if I work with a class like Uuid4:

```
>>> import uuid
>>> u = uuid.uuid4()
>>> u
UUID('cf27caba-d109-403c-a09e-fc59fb2a57a4')
```

Another object that act like this is the one created with scapy:

```
# scapy
Welcome to Scapy
>>>
>>> i = IP()
>>> i.src = '192.168.1.12'
>>> i
<IP src=192.168.1.12 |>
```

So my goal is to create a MyObject class that acts like Uuid4() or IP() while called:

```
MyObject(a='12') or MyObject(12) or <MyObject a=12 |>
```

I thought it was how the class is defined, but looking at the Uuid4() sourcecode gives me no hint on this...
Or am I missing something?!

Comment: I think you want to write the `__repr__` method in your class, and have that describe the contents of the instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `__repr__` method on your class, and have it describe the contents of class instance.

For instance, UUID has this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'UUID(%r)' % str(self)
```

For your class, you could write this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'MyClass(%r)'%(self.a,)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the `__repr__` method to return the string you want.

```
class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 12

    def __repr__(self):
        return "MyObject(%s)" % (self.a,)
```

The general rule is that when possible, `repr(a)` should return a string that could be (or at least resembles one that could be) evaluated to create an object identical to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to implement **repr**() or **str**() in your class

for example :

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.a
```

and when you will do

```
print i
```

you will get what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

You should override the `__repr__` and `__str__` methods with your version of the string / representation of the class

```
class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 12

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'MyObject(a=%s)' % self.a

    def __str__(self):
        return 'MyObject(a=%s)' % self.a

i = MyObject()
i
>> MyObject(a=12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `__str__` method:

```
class MyObject(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.a = 12
   def __str__(self):
      return "<MyObject a={} |>".format(self.a)
i = MyObject()
print(i)
```

Output:

```
<MyObject a=12 |>
```